# Enabling breaking news notifications on Sierra

Tags: macos, safari, notifications, firefox

On a new system running MacOS Sierra, how to enable notifications for the NY Times, or any other news source?

A client saw that my older MBP running Yosemite gets breaking news from the NY Times, and asked me to set it up on his shiny new 2016 MBP running Sierra. No joy -- neither Safari nor Firefox pop up a notifications request from nytimes.com.

Further, notifications cannot be added manually in System Preferences/Notifications or in Safari's Preferences/Notifications.

Is there some other way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just go to the Times Breaking News site and click Allow when it asks if you want alerts? I've done this on other sites, not the Times, but I assume it's similar on that site.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Per the response below, it required clearing the Safari cache and restarting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this!

[*macOS Sierra v10.12.1  &  Safari v10.0.1*]

1. Navigate to Safari>Preferences
2. Make sure **Safari Push Notifications are enabled** at the bottom of the Notifications Pane
3. **Delete Safari Caches** and make sure **Cookies and Website Data are enabled** in the Privacy Plane

   -You may be able to get away with just **deleting "nytimes.com"**

[image]

4. Make sure **JavaScript is Enabled** in the Security Pane
5. **Restart Safari** and **surf to nytimes.com**

[image]

*Please let me know if you still have any trouble!*